# How to combine a column from a data table to panel data structure

Tags: r, cbind, plm

I have been working with a large panel data set. My simple data set look like below.

```
+--------+------+------+-----+-----+--------+
|  Time  | Firm | Land | Lab | Cap |   GL   |
+--------+------+------+-----+-----+--------+
| Jan-00 | A    |   25 | 261 |  13 | 161521 |
| Feb-00 | A    |   25 | 334 |  15 | 142452 |
| Mar-00 | A    |   25 | 156 |  14 | 365697 |
| Apr-00 | A    |   28 | 134 |  12 | 355789 |
| May-00 | A    |   28 | 159 |  15 | 376843 |
| Jun-00 | A    |   28 | 119 |  12 | 258762 |
| Jul-00 | A    |   28 |  41 |  45 | 255447 |
| Aug-00 | A    |   28 | 247 |  75 | 188545 |
| Sep-00 | A    |   28 | 251 |  41 | 213663 |
| Oct-00 | A    |   30 |  62 |  12 | 273209 |
| Nov-00 | A    |   30 | 525 |  15 | 317468 |
| Dec-00 | A    |   30 | 217 |  16 | 238668 |
| Jan-01 | B    |   42 | 298 |  42 | 241286 |
| Feb-01 | B    |   42 | 109 |  45 | 135288 |
| Mar-01 | B    |   42 |   7 |  24 | 363609 |
| Apr-01 | B    |   42 |  12 |  56 | 318472 |
| May-01 | B    |   42 |   0 |  12 | 446279 |
| Jun-01 | B    |   45 |  50 |  12 | 390230 |
| Jul-01 | B    |   45 | 143 |  45 | 118945 |
| Aug-01 | B    |   45 |  85 |  25 | 174887 |
| Sep-01 | B    |   45 |  80 |  15 | 183770 |
| Oct-01 | B    |   45 | 214 |  12 | 197832 |
| Nov-01 | B    |   45 | 525 |  15 | 317468 |
| Dec-01 | B    |   45 | 217 |  16 | 238668 |
+--------+------+------+-----+-----+--------+
```

The above dataframe can be accessed using the following codes.

```
structure(list(Time = structure(c(9L, 7L, 15L, 1L, 17L, 13L, 
11L, 3L, 23L, 21L, 19L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 16L, 2L, 18L, 14L, 12L, 
4L, 24L, 22L, 20L, 6L), .Label = c("Apr-00", "Apr-01", "Aug-00", 
"Aug-01", "Dec-00", "Dec-01", "Feb-00", "Feb-01", "Jan-00", "Jan-01", 
"Jul-00", "Jul-01", "Jun-00", "Jun-01", "Mar-00", "Mar-01", "May-00", 
"May-01", "Nov-00", "Nov-01", "Oct-00", "Oct-01", "Sep-00", "Sep-01"
), class = "factor"), Firm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Land = c(25L, 
25L, 25L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 42L, 42L, 
42L, 42L, 42L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L), Lab = c(261L, 
334L, 156L, 134L, 159L, 119L, 41L, 247L, 251L, 62L, 525L, 217L, 
298L, 109L, 7L, 12L, 0L, 50L, 143L, 85L, 80L, 214L, 525L, 217L
), Cap = c(13L, 15L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 45L, 75L, 41L, 12L, 
15L, 16L, 42L, 45L, 24L, 56L, 12L, 12L, 45L, 25L, 15L, 12L, 15L, 
16L), GL = c(161521L, 142452L, 365697L, 355789L, 376843L, 258762L, 
255447L, 188545L, 213663L, 273209L, 317468L, 238668L, 241286L, 
135288L, 363609L, 318472L, 446279L, 390230L, 118945L, 174887L, 
183770L, 197832L, 317468L, 238668L)), .Names = c("Time", "Firm", 
"Land", "Lab", "Cap", "GL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

I converted the data into a panel structure as below.

```
library(zoo)
library(plm)

Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
dat["time1"] <- as.yearmon(dat$Time,format="%b-%y")
pdat <-pdata.frame(dat,index=c("Firm","time1"))
```

## Original Analysis

```
pdat$Cap.lag.ln<-lag(log(pdat$Cap), 1)
pdat$Cap.2lag.ln<-lag(log(pdat$Cap), 2)
pdat$Lab.ln<-log(pdat$Lab+1)
pdat$Lab.lag.ln<-lag(log(pdat$Lab+1), 1)

Model1<- plm(log(Land) ~ Cap.lag.ln + Cap.2lag.ln + Lab.ln + Lab.lag.ln,
         model = "within", data=pdat)
summary(Model1)

FV_Log <- data.table(Model1$model[[1]] - Model1$residuals)
```

Just to omit the NAs in pdat resulted from lags to combine fitted values

```
pdat2<-na.omit(pdat)
```

## The problem

I want to combine these fitted values to the pdat2 but need to retain the panel structure as it is. But if I go for the following cbind then the panel structure is disappeared.

```
pdat3 <-cbind(pdat2,FV_Log)
```

Even I tried omitting old variables and the following way.

```
pdat$Cap<-NULL
pdat$Lab<-NULL
pdat2 <- na.omit(pdat)
pdat2$FV_Log <- (Model1$model[[1]] - Model1$residuals)

and run my model2 using data=pdat2 but the following error message comes up.
Model2<-plm(log(GL)~ Cap.lag.ln + Cap.2lag.ln + Lab.ln + Lab.lag.ln
+ FV_Log, data=pdat2, model = "within")

**Error in model.matrix.pFormula(formula, data, rhs = 1, model = model,  : 
NA in the individual index variable
In addition: Warning message:
In `[.data.frame`(index, as.numeric(rownames(mf)), ) :
NAs introduced by coercion**
```

Can anybody please assist me to identify this problem and to run the model 2 in plm structure. Thank you

Comment: Best way to get help is to post everything relevant to the question here, inline.

Comment: I edited the post to include the code you referenced. This needs to get peer-reviewed and so may not appear right away. Please let me know if the code I included is wrong. In the meantime, see my answer below.

Comment: Why are you using `data.table`?

Comment: Actually I don't want to but I just use a way to combine the data from FV_Log. Even without data.table I can get it to pdat2 but for some reason model2 is not working for me

Comment: @Gopala. I edited my question and provided more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating my answer after OP provided code needed for replication.

I think using data.table to create FV_Log is a complicating factor.

I ran the following codes immediately after the creation of pdat3 above.

```
# convert FV_Log to just data.frame
FV_Log<-data.frame(FV_Log)

# bind FV_Log to pdat2 using use pdata.frame to preserve structure.
pdat3_fix<-pdata.frame(cbind(pdat2,FV_Log),index=c("Firm","time1"))
```

Here is pdat3_fix, which is identical to pdat2 with the exception of the new column:

[image]

Note that the resulting data.frame is also an object of class pdata.frame:

```
> class(pdat3_fix)
[1] "pdata.frame" "data.frame"
```

Comment: I edited my question and you may see that my fitted number of observations are 20 and pdat2 is also 20. But I need to combine this fitted value column to pdat2 but the pdata.frame structure should be secured.

Comment: the last code is not working and produces this error message.              Error in `[.data.frame`(reg_model_wFV, , c("mergeID", "FV_Log.V1"), with = F) : 
  unused argument (with = F)

Comment: @Doo. Thanks for editing your original post. I can re-work my solution to fit the code above. You're getting that error because my solution was built assuming you were working with data.tables (which you were doing before). But since you're not using data.tables anymore, the with= parameter in the second argument of merge() is causing an error because reg_model_wFV is not longer a data.table...it is only a data.frame. You can try removing the ", with=F"